# Error with bash script after "cat"ing one text file to another

Tags: bash, cat

I made a very simple script (`ping_hostnames.sh`) to go through a list of IP's/hostnames in a file `hostnames.txt` and ping them:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

hostnameCount=`cat hostnames.txt | wc -l`
i=1

while [ $i -le $hostnameCount ]
do
  ping -c 3 $(sed -n ${i}p hostnames.txt)
  i=$(( i+1 ))
done
```

I then do:

```
cat file_with_ip_list.txt >> hostnames.txt
```

The `hostnames.txt` now looks like:

```
192.168.1.0
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
```

Then running the script (`./ping_hostnames.sh`) gives an error:

```
: Name or service not known
```

However, if I manually copy/paste the data from `file_with_ip_list.txt` to `hostnames.txt` with a text editor, it works just fine. Is there some sort of type casting going on with `cat` or something?

Comment: Welcome, what is the content of `hostnames.txt`?

Comment: Most likely `file_with_ip_list.txt` has Windows-style (CRLF) line endings

Comment: The file has been copied from Windows to RedHat so that's probably it, didn't know that was a thing. How would I know that in the future?

Comment: @timmio888 the fact that there is nothing to the left of the `:` is what really gives it away; then I checked with `ping "$(printf '%s\r\n' localhost)"` and got an identical error message. If you use the `file` command on the file, it will likely report `ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question: Instead of `cat hostnames.txt | wc -l`, use `wc -l hostnames.txt`. Actually, you don't need the `wc` at all, and your loop could be like this: `for host in $(cat hostnames.txt); do ping -c3 "$host"; done`

Comment: Don't use `for host in` either -- to read a file line-by-line, use a `while read ...` loop. See [BashFAQ #1: How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) Note: if you use `while IFS=$'\r' read ...` (and are using bash, not a brand-x shell), it'll auto-trim the carriage return from the end of the line.

Comment: Oh, and for how to tell if the file's in DOS/Windows format, use `file file_with_ip_list.txt` and see if it says something like "ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators". More info in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings).

Answer (score 1):

@steeldriver in the comments answered it: "invisible" CRLF line endings caused this issue, and now that I know, I can use numerous workarounds to this. Also, thank you to everyone else in the comments for helping me improve my code! While I'm not a complete newbie to BASH, I still have much to learn!

Answer (score 0):

See if this will work with the hostname.txt.  It might be that `wc -l` is getting the line count off by one or something like that.

```
for f in $(cat hostnames.txt); do ping -c 3 ${f}; done
```